# Problem with Ubuntu Software Center after installing GNOME

Tags: gnome, software-center, 13.04

I recently decided to install GNOME 3.8 on my Ubuntu 13.04 system, but doing so caused a problem with Ubuntu Software Center. The left side of the window, displaying all the available software categories, is completely unreadable! Is there any way to fix this?[image: Ubuntu Software Center - categories are unreadable]

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the Ubuntu Desktop.

Open the terminal then copy & paste the following command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Enter your password when prompted & press Enter.

Comment: Not applicable. apt-get responds with "ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version."

Comment: I took it upon myself to run a Web search on my problem, and I found this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1173611
From what I can see, it looks like I'll need to uninstall GTK 3.8. But what's the correct package name for "apt-get remove" to do that?